# IntelliJ and scala-compiler-interfaces

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a problem with IntelliJ 14.1.4 and Scala plugin.

when I try to debug or run my scala classes I get the following exception.

> Error:scalac: Error: Could not create directory
>   C:\Users\XXXXXX.idea-build\scala-compiler-interfaces\0.13.5-idea-4AF4B3950909BF01BBBF06BC6D564796
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create directory
>   C:\Users\EH2SAF7.idea-build\scala-compiler-interfaces\0.13.5-idea-4AF4B3950909BF01BBBF06BC6D564796

I know the reason, in the company that I work my user has no write permissions here, IntelliJ or Scala plugin is not able to create this directory.

So I searched the internet I found that I have to set `user.home` to other directory or `scala.compiler.interfaces.dir` to another directory.

I tried to put these values to Environment Variables, into

> 'idea.properties', 'idea.exe.vmoptions', 'idea64.exe.vmoptions',
>   'Scala Compiler'-> 'Additional compiler options', 'Scala Compile
>   Server' -> 'JVM parameters'

none works.

The moment I say run or debug it tries to write

> 'C:\Users\XXXXXX.idea-build\scala-compiler-interfaces\0.13.5-idea-4AF4B3950909BF01BBBF06BC6D564796'.

Can anybody has an idea how can I fix this?

Thx for answers.

Answer (score 0):

after lots of fighting and sheer luck, I found the solution....

The entry 'scala.compiler.interfaces.dir' should not go to

'idea.properties', 'idea.exe.vmoptions', 'idea64.exe.vmoptions'

but at IntelliJ Settings->Compiler->Scala Compiler->Additional Compiler Options but if you have additional entries there, remember that those must be separated with LineBreak and another tricky part, even you click apply the setting is only effective if you restart the IntelliJ.

I hope this helps somebody.